# Install a specific version of a role with Ansible Galaxy

Tags: ansible, ansible-role, ansible-galaxy

I'm installing an ansible role with:

```bash
ansible-galaxy install geerlingguy.java
```

But this command install the latest version.

I need to install an old version like:

```bash
ansible-galaxy install geerlingguy.java:1.10.0
```

But this command launches this error:

```bash
ansible-galaxy install geerlingguy.java:1.10.0
- downloading role '0', owned by geerlingguy.java%3A1.10
[WARNING]: - geerlingguy.java:1.10.0 was NOT installed successfully: - sorry, geerlingguy.java:1.10.0 was not found on https://galaxy.ansible.com/api/.
ERROR! - you can use --ignore-errors to skip failed roles and finish processing the list.
```

Comment: [_Install a specific version of a role by appending **a comma** and a version tag._](https://galaxy.ansible.com/docs/using/installing.html#role-versions) and not a colon, as you are trying to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As β.εηοιτ.βε indicated, the correct command was:

```bash
ansible-galaxy install geerlingguy.java,1.10.0
```